# Swift - Rotate an image, then zoom in and crop to keep width/height aspect ratio intact

Tags: swift, image, rotation, transform, crop

If the title isn't clear, open Photos app on your iPhone and edit a picture. Try the rotation tool. The frame don't rotate, only the image does and zoom in to stay in the frame.

Here is a picture of this:

[image: Rotation photo app tool]

I would like to copy this comportment in my Swift project. It means rotating an image (it can be UIImage, CIImage or CGImage) but crop it keeping the same width/height ratio.

Where should I begin ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's <strike>an app</strike> a filter for that. [CIStraightenFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIStraightenFilter) rotates an image by any amount while stretching it and cropping it to maintain the original dimensions:

```
let image: CIImage = /* my image 480x320 */
let rotated = image.applyingFilter("CIStraightenFilter", 
    withInputParameters: [ kCIInputAngleKey: Double.pi / 6 ]) // 30 degrees 
rotated.extent // still 480x320
```

Here's some examples (rotations of zero, 15°, 30°, and 45°):

[image: no rotation]
[image: rotate by π/12 (15 degrees)]
[image: rotate by π/6 (30 degrees)]
[image: rotate by π/4 (45 degrees)]

Comment: Thank you it's working well ! I didn't know about this filter. I added this line of code to create a CGImage if anyone needs it:

| let cgImage = context.createCGImage(rotated, from: rotated.extent) |